# Getting value from TCNT0 AVR

Tags: timer, avr, avr-studio4

I have a timer which increments by one every 256 cycles. Is there a way that i can get the value from TCNT0 at the point it is called.

I am using AVR Studio 4 and have tried using `ldi temp, TCNT0` but i always seem to get 32 which is its address.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If TCNT0 is within I/O space then you can use `IN` to retrieve its value, otherwise you will need to use `LDS` to load it from its memory address (which is usually offset by 0x20 from the I/O register location).

```
in tmp,TCNT0
```